# Example of "semi-definite" question?

Tags: logic

I read that mathematical logic can have a "semi-definite" question but what does it mean and is there an easy example? Is it a yes-or-no question where there is no method for one of the answers?

For example, you state P(x,y) and only given that it is true, there is a method to prove it and there is no method to prove it if it is false.

Did I understand?

Comment: Where did you read this? "semi-definite" is not a standard term. Yes, it's true that there's a mechanical way (an algorithm) to show that a statement follows from other statements when it does follow, and that in general there isn't an algorithm to show that a statement does *not* follow from others. ¶
Whether you understood or not depends on what the text you read says :)

Comment: Maybe [Semidecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Semidecidability) ?

Comment: I have the lecture notes and can look at it again. It was the lecture notes where the course book was Symbolic Logic by Graeme Forbes.